# Google Maps API - cannot find the google places ID for my business

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been searching for solutions in this forum but I cannot find any:

I cannot find my business place ID, which I need for the google reviews snippet.

I type my business name in the placeID finder and nothing shows up. I can only look up the address of the building where my business is, but not my actual business.

my business page:
https://business.google.com/b/106802106987470032893/dashboard/l/06489107232401690502?pageId=106802106987470032893

my google maps link: https://www.google.com/maps/place/CherryLaser+laser+cutting+and+engraving+services/@34.0454354,-118.2509478,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x80c2c63593d2cbab:0x9417c55fe89ca04b!2sCherryLaser+laser+cutting+and+engraving+services!8m2!3d34.0454354!4d-118.2487591!3m4!1s0x80c2c63593d2cbab:0x9417c55fe89ca04b!8m2!3d34.0454354!4d-118.2487591

I'm also trying to get hold of google map api support or any human at google, with no luck. Anybody knows where I can find the customer support number?
Thanks

Comment: Place ID: `ChIJq8vSkzXGwoARS6Cc6F_FF5Q` found it using a place search with the API.

Answer (score 1):

I executed Places API text search request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=CherryLaser%20laser%20cutting%20and%20engraving%20services&key=YOUR_API_KEY

and got this result:

```
{
    "html_attributions":[
     ],
    "results":[
        {
            "formatted_address":"533 S Los Angeles St, Los Angeles, CA 90013, United States",
            "geometry":{
                "location":{
                    "lat":34.0454354,
                    "lng":-118.2487591
                }
            },
      "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
  "id":"ef1923650a198ab42c3335c4f49d2ed52c9680fd",
  "name":"CherryLaser laser cutting and engraving services",
  "opening_hours":{
    "open_now":true,
    "weekday_text":[

    ]
  },
  "photos":[
    {
      "height":450,
      "html_attributions":[
        "CherryLaser laser cutting and engraving services"
      ],
      "photo_reference":"CoQBcwAAAAUiQHaDoHqUqnWuOMdk9JywgVZJl7rb78dqIETdN0KktPnqkWv0XRsKl-UXqorIvWG3icTejJ_940XJSj0l3mrvhndafNrZCkbGvT4VMZGJ0pSdO00rTQCP07LdtYAuvDG19go2A6pYjTfka7dynxTAH1ehzEnz9Sdm8WDnJcjnEhA-qRmXzs9cnEHN3ZHzleR7GhRqQYi4c3z-BanOl369gjvCQp7hpw",
      "width":1024
    }
  ],
  "place_id":"ChIJq8vSkzXGwoARS6Cc6F_FF5Q",
  "reference":"CpQBhQAAAGwY3h9oSu4ec696UxnIJOcWqy16HXoukpXcjr0p70ifB8xDMWNHs6Bh1Frebr60YuxsjFvSqh_KIYTAGWfbpW1OZ-kVqG0VH8sfwd9Ga8ot9moKSm7z_1mWIqqkVq6ufs_BrfWGp-yDypp84xN07LdgxZ32p69bIQypgY2tXBtVohq8oxgp5IEtrS0Q23eX7RIQsSYPuSGdOqw6el5SJN6GihoU5-K2Ogh2ml2wEEPwnSCoW83hm_0",
  "types":[
    "point_of_interest","establishment"
  ]
}
],
"status":"OK"
}
```

So the place ID for your business is ChIJq8vSkzXGwoARS6Cc6F_FF5Q.

You can check details with Places API details request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJq8vSkzXGwoARS6Cc6F_FF5Q&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: thank you so much, that helps but 'm still not able to solve my problem, I should have been clearer: I'm using google review for WP ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-places-reviews/ ) and the problem is that Im not able to find my business in the look-up "location" section ( screenshot here ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-places-reviews/screenshots/ ) .